# Stream Data from azure stream analytics

Tags: powerbi, azure-stream-analytics

I have real time data coming from azure stream anaytics. I have enabled history data as I want to see historical events in my dashboard. However, I need to show most recent message value in gauge. Is there a way to get latest message value an show it on dashboard as single value.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Stream Analytics job PowerBI output writes data to Streaming Dataset, which allows you show last value, or most resent values on your dashboard. Have a look at this document: [Real-time streaming in Power BI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-real-time-streaming/)